# A node module without typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am using the module [passport-google-oauth20](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2) and Typescript version 2.2.1 with `noImplicitAny` set to true. I tried to install the typings with

```
yarn add @types/passport-google-oauth20
```

but I receive the error

```
error Couldn't find package "@types/passport-google-oauth20" on the "npm" registry.
```

When I import the module with `import {Strategy} from 'passport-google-oauth20';` I get the error `error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'passport-google-oauth20'. ... implicitly has an 'any' type.` I want to get rid of this error.

As alternative to `@types/passport-google-oauth20` I found typings [here](https://github.com/types/npm-passport-google-oauth20) and installed it via the [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) command. Then I referenced it with

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

But I get the error `error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Strategy'.`.

Then I tried to write my own type file `passport-google-oauth20.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="passport"/>

import passport = require('passport');

declare class Strategy implements passport.Strategy {
    public name: string;
    public constructor(options: IStrategyOption,
                verify: (accessToken: string,
                         refreshToken: string,
                         profile: Profile,
                         done: (error: any, user?: any, info?: any) => void) => void);
}
```

and include it with `/// <reference path="./passport-google-oauth20.d.ts" />`. Now I get again

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'passport-google-oauth20'... implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

When I require it

```
const google = require('passport-google-oauth20');
...
public create(): google.Strategy {
```

I get `error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.`. When I change the code to

```
const Strategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
...
public create(): Strategy {
```

I get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Strategy'.`.

So all I want to do is use `passport-google-oauth20` with `noImplicitAny`. Could someone tell me how? Normally I don't have problems when no typing is given, I just switch to `require` so I want to learn what is special in this case.

**Update:** I am not sure if this issue here addresses my problem: [import/require deprecation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11340)

Comment: if the module is not complicated, and you don't need the extra type safety, you could just `require` it, and use it as a regular js object, and add a TODO to check if typings are available..

Comment: Updated question.